# When a new item is added to SharePoint list, send email notification to users matching item category

Tags: build-automation, power-automate

I'm trying to build a workflow in Microsoft Power Automate (Microsoft Flow), where users will get email notification when a new item is added to the SharePoint list, but only in case if item is relevant to their responsibilities area (based on one field value from the item, i.e. 'Market').

I believe it should look like this:

1. A new item is created in SharePoint list
2. Get 'Market' field value from created item.
3. VLOOKUP Market field value in connected spreadsheet, where we have a list of 'Markets' and corresponding responsible for market users, return email address.
4. Send customized email notification to returned email.

Whilst step 1 and 4 are clear and easy to do, I cannot find a way to do step 2 and 3 (I'm new to Microsoft 365 environment).

Is it possible to do in Power Automate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

should be possible with Power Automate:

Suppose follwing flow:

Step 1: "When an item is created" - this triggers when a new item is added and lets you use the values of each column in the next steps.

Step 2: Excel-Online - Get row

- point to the excel file
- select the desired table
- name the colum that you want to search
- under "Key Value" you should have the option to "Insert parameters from previous steps" - just select the desired field

Step 3: Send email

- as with Step 2 you should now be able to select the results from Step 2 (e-mail address) and put it in the to: field.